# llvm calling an external function with char * as argument

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

I want to call an external function with char * as argument in a created call but I have been struggling.

I tried looking at the documents but it only shows how to pass constant integers.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
// not sure if the line below is correct. I am trying to call an external function: FPRCLAP_path(char * string)
std::vector<llvm::Type*> arg_types = {llvm::Type::getInt8PtrTy(context)};

llvm::FunctionType *function_type = llvm::FunctionType::get(llvm::Type::getVoidTy(context), arg_types, false);
llvm::FunctionCallee instrumentation_function = function.getParent()->getOrInsertFunction("FPRCLAP_path", function_type);
```

```
llvm::IRBuilder<> builder(&instruction);
builder.SetInsertPoint(&basic_block, ++builder.GetInsertPoint());
// I want to pass a string for instrumentation but I am not sure how to do it using llvm. I think I am supposed to allocate a string or reference an existing string.
llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value*> arguments = {???};
builder.CreateCall(instrumentation_function, arguments);
```

Comment: Allocating a constant string (by which I mean the C thing rather than an instance of a sensible string class) [isn't at all difficult](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantDataArray.html#a3edef3fa47c611d3d10606591213e57b). The return value of getString() is a Value (via about a half-dozen intermediate classes) so you can use it as an operand for the call Instruction. Allocating something modifiable is more work, but don't worry, keep struggling, it'll come to you.

Comment: @arnt Thank you. I will try that when I am back to my research computer. Will update if I have any further questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your code

```
llvm::IRBuilder<> builder(&instruction);
builder.SetInsertPoint(&basic_block, ++builder.GetInsertPoint());
// I want to pass a string for instrumentation but I am not sure how to do it using llvm. I think I am supposed to allocate a string or reference an existing string.
llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value*> arguments = {???};
builder.CreateCall(instrumentation_function, arguments);
```

The following snippet should do what you want

LLVM optimisation will make the string local, if it is run. If you generate IR without optimisation you might be allowed to be a bit sloppy.

```
//str is a char*
 llvm::Value *strPointer = program->builder.CreateGlobalStringPtr(str);
//Using a Vector instead of ArrayRef
 const std::vector<llvm::Value *> args{strPointer};
 builder.CreateCall(instrumentation_function, args);
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to come back here until I saw the notification. I managed to do it with your help. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem mate : )